# plot textboxes and fill colors between vertical lines in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram, plot-annotations

based on another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49630427/how-to-plot-normal-distribution-with-percentage-of-data-as-label-in-each-band-bi) i got this code:

```
data =  np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=2000)
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
import numpy as np
import scipy
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def _plot(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        n_bins = 50
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
        n, bins, patches = axes.hist(df[col], n_bins, density=True, alpha=.1, edgecolor='black' )
        mu = df[col].mean()
        sigma = df[col].std()
        pdf = 1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-(bins-mu)**2/(2*sigma**2))

        #probability density function
        axes.plot(bins, pdf, color='green', alpha=.6)

        #dashed lines
        plt.axvline(np.mean(df_data[0]),color='b', linestyle='-.')
        plt.axvline(np.mean(df_data[0]-sigma),color='b', linestyle='-.')
        plt.axvline(np.mean(df_data[0]-2*sigma),color='b', linestyle='-.')
        plt.axvline(np.mean(df_data[0]-3*sigma),color='b', linestyle='-.')
        plt.axvline(min(df_data[0]),color='r', linestyle='-.')
        plt.axvline(np.mean(df_data[0]+sigma),color='b', linestyle='-.')
        plt.axvline(np.mean(df_data[0]+2*sigma),color='b', linestyle='-.')
        plt.axvline(np.mean(df_data[0]+3*sigma),color='b', linestyle='-.')
        plt.axvline(max(df_data[0]),color='r', linestyle='-.')
        

        plt.ylabel('Probability Density')
        plt.xlabel('Values')

        print(mu)
        print(sigma)

_plot(df_data)
```

Which returns me this nice plot:
[image]

As you can see the blue vertical lines indicate borders set by multiples of standard deviations. I would like to add the following information and color coding, which I now quickly placed in powerpoint:

[image]

I tried to mess with the `plt.fill_between` function but didnt really get anything useful. Also I do not know how to write something, like the mu+l*sigma here, *above* the plot. How can i achieve the second picture based on what I have?

EDIT:
solved by @Trenton McKinney

[image]
Putting new boxes inside the colored boxes:

```
for i, (x, c) in enumerate(locs[:-1]):
            axes.axvspan(x, locs[i + 1][0], alpha=0.2, color=c)
            tx = (x + locs[i + 1][0]) / 2
            axes.text(tx, y1/2, f'Zustand {i + 1}', {'ha': 'center', 'va': 'center'}, rotation=90)
            if i<4:
                axes.text(tx, y1/1.25, r"$\mu$" + "-" + f"{4-i}"+ "$\cdot$" + "$\sigma$" , {'ha': 'center', 'va': 'center'}, rotation=90, bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.8, edgecolor='black'))
            else:
                axes.text(tx, y1/1.25, r"$\mu$" + "+" + f"{i-4 + 1}"+ "$\cdot$" + "$\sigma$" , {'ha': 'center', 'va': 'center'}, rotation=90, bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.8, edgecolor='black'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It will be easier to create a container with all of the values for the vertical lines because those values will be reused for placing the lines, and determining the `axvspan` and `text` placement. In this case, a dictionary is used.
- See inline notation for explanations
- Use [`.Axes.axvspan`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvspan.html) to fill between vertical positions

  - [How to highlight specific x-value ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8270981/7758804)
- See [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression (take union of dictionaries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38987/7758804)
- Add text to the plot with [`.Axes.text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html)
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`**

```py
# extra imports
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import zip_longest

np.random.seed(2022)
data =  np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=2000)
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)


def _plot(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        n_bins = 50
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
        n, bins, patches = axes.hist(df[col], n_bins, density=True, alpha=.1, edgecolor='black' )
        mu = df[col].mean()
        sigma = df[col].std()
        pdf = 1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-(bins-mu)**2/(2*sigma**2))

        #probability density function
        axes.plot(bins, pdf, color='green', alpha=.6)
        
        # get ylim to position the text
        y0, y1 = axes.get_ylim()
        
        # create a dict for all the x values for vertical lines with the line color
        muu = {mu: 'b'}
        mm = {df_data[0].min(): 'r', df_data[0].max(): 'r'}
        mun = {df_data[0].sub(v*sigma).mean(): 'b' for v in range(1, 4)}
        mup = {df_data[0].add(v*sigma).mean(): 'b' for v in range(1, 4)}
        
        # combine the dicts: | requires python 3.9+. See linked SO answer for additional opitons to combine the dicts
        vals = muu | mm | mun | mup
        
        # order the keys (x values) from smallest to largest
        vals = OrderedDict(sorted(vals.items()))
        
        # plot the dashed lines
        for x, c in vals.items():
            plt.axvline(x, color=c, linestyle='-.')
            
        # combine the x values with colors of the stages
        locs = list(zip_longest(vals.keys(), ['blue', 'brown']*4))
        
        # iterate through all but the last value, and add the vspan and the text
        for i, (x, c) in enumerate(locs[:-1]):
            axes.axvspan(x, locs[i + 1][0], alpha=0.2, color=c)
            tx = (x + locs[i + 1][0]) / 2
            axes.text(tx, y1/2, f'Stage {i + 1}', {'ha': 'center', 'va': 'center'}, rotation=90)

        plt.ylabel('Probability Density')
        plt.xlabel('Values')

        print(mu)
        print(sigma)

    
_plot(df_data)
```

[image]

### Update for additional annotations

```py
        # extra annotations
        sign = [f'µ - {v}σ' for v in range(4, 0, -1)]
        sigp = [f'µ + {v}σ' for v in range(1, 5)]
        anno = sign + sigp
        
        # iterate through all but the last value and add the vspan and the text
        for i, (x, c) in enumerate(locs[:-1]):
            axes.axvspan(x, locs[i + 1][0], alpha=0.2, color=c)
            tx = (x + locs[i + 1][0]) / 2
            axes.text(tx, y1/2, f'Stage {i + 1}: {anno[i]}', {'ha': 'center', 'va': 'center'}, rotation=90)
```

[image]

Comment: wow that's very nice! Thanks a lot! Follow up question regarding the secondary x axis above the plot, can i do that somehow with manual tiks?

Comment: actually ill just put that inside the box, with the same axes.text principle just with no rotation. Thanks again!

Comment: indeed, that's also very readable. I have customized it a bit further, see my update in the original post. I'll add the relevant lines for anyone reading this in the future and wanting something similar